# How often does a problem occur per day and location?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, group-by

I have dataframe like this:

```
Date                  Location_ID   Problem_ID  
---------------------+------------+----------  
2013-01-02 10:00:00  | 1          |  43  
2012-08-09 23:03:01  | 5          |  2  
...
```

How can I count how often a Problem occurs per day and per Location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with converting `Date` column to [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html)s or [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) with aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
print (df)
                  Date  Location_ID  Problem_ID
0  2013-01-02 10:00:00            1          43
1  2012-08-09 23:03:01            5           2

#if necessary convert column to datetimes 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df1 = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.date, 'Location_ID']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
         Date  Location_ID  count
0  2012-08-09            5      1
1  2013-01-02            1      1
```

Or:

```
df1 = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D'), 'Location_ID'])
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='count'))
```

---

If first column is index:

```
print (df)
                     Location_ID  Problem_ID
Date                                        
2013-01-02 10:00:00            1          43
2012-08-09 23:03:01            5           2


df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df1 = (df.groupby([df.index.date, 'Location_ID'])
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='count')
        .rename(columns={'level_0':'Date'}))
print (df1)
         Date  Location_ID  count
0  2012-08-09            5      1
1  2013-01-02            1      1
```

---

```
df1 = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='Date', freq='D'), 'Location_ID'])
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='count'))
```